# Вопрос по MySQL

Tags: mysql

Добрый вечер. Мне нужно изменить существующий SQL запрос:

```
$query = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(image) as product_image,
                            p.id as product_id, p.title as product_title, p.description as product_description, p.description1 as product_description1,
                            p.text as product_text, p.keywords as product_keywords, p.price as product_price,
                            p.quantity as product_quantity, p.availability as product_availability, p.category as product_category,
                            p.cnc as product_cnc
                        FROM images i 
                        INNER JOIN products p ON (p.id = i.product_id) 
                        GROUP BY p.id";
```

Нужно добавить условие `WHERE product_availability == 1`. Помогите решить задачу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил задачу используя HAVING.